# Bind the drop down using JQuery

Tags: jquery, binding

This is my aspx coding

```
  [WebMethod]
    public static CountryDetails[] BindDatatoDropdown()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        List<CountryDetails> details = new List<CountryDetails>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DEVSYS;Initial Catalog=Items;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*****"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ItemTypeID,ItemType FROM ItemTypeTable", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    CountryDetails country = new CountryDetails();
                    country.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(dtrow["ItemTypeID"].ToString());
                    country.CountryName = dtrow["ItemType"].ToString();
                    details.Add(country);
                }
            }
        }
        return details.ToArray();
    }
    public class CountryDetails
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
```

i want to bind the drop down using Jquery. but my it shows only error alert
This is my design coding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.selectboxes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/BindDatatoDropdown",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("hi");
                $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                     $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(value.CountryId).html(value.CountryName));
                });
            },
             error: function ajaxError(response) {
            alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Just i want t bind the item details in drop down while page load. It always show the alert of error. It says 500 internal server error

Comment: I have found the issue. The Jquery script only bind limited data. It bind only nearly 1000 data. I suppose to bind 2000 so that it shows error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If still need help please

ASPX CODE:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">

        <title></title>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax
                  ({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "test.aspx/options",
                      data: '',
                      contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (data) {

                          var lankanListArray = JSON.parse(data.d);



                          // running a loop
                          $.each(lankanListArray, function (index, value) {
                              $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(this.name).html(this.price));
                          });




                      },
                      error: function (err) {

                      }
                  });

            });
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>



    C# CODE


    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using MailDLL;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        [WebMethod]
        public static string options()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            landmarkEntities A = new landmarkEntities();
            var b = A.sp_test().ToList();


            List<Test1> c=new List<Test1>();
            foreach (var s in b)
            {
                Test1 testobj = new Test1();
                testobj.name = s.Name;
                testobj.price = s.price;
                c.Add(testobj);

            }

            string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(c);
            return jsonString;

        }

        public class Test1
        {
            public Test1(string _name, string _price)
            {
                name = _name;
                price = _price;


            }
            public Test1()
            { }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string price { get; set; }

        }   


    }


first add refrence to these js files in your application.

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>



then create class that will hold the data

 public class Test1
    {
        public Test1(string _name, string _price)
        {
            name = _name;
            price = _price;


        }
        public Test1()
        { }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }

    }




add using System.Web.Script.Serialization; in your cs page so that you can use JavaScriptSerializer.
the create a list of type class.
Loop through the data.

inside loop create object of a class.
assign the data that you had fetched to the class,
add the object to the list of type class.

then Serialize the list using serializer.Serialize() function.And return as string.

 string jsonString = serializer.Serialize(c);
        return jsonString;
```